# Button text in JTable renderer not visible. Why?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a custom cell renderer set in JTable and it works but instead an "x" visible on buttons being table cells I see "..." (three dots). What did I miss ??

```
  /***************************************************************************
 * Listener reagujący na dodanie nowej wartości
 **************************************************************************/
private static class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements
        TableCellRenderer {
    /***********************************************************************
     * Konstruktor
     **********************************************************************/
    public ButtonRenderer() {
        super("x");
    }

    /***********************************************************************
     * @see TableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable, Object,
     *      boolean, boolean, int, int)
     **********************************************************************/
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the button isn't large enough to contain the rendered "x" plus the padding around it.

A solution would be to enlarge the table cell or reduce the padding (always assuming that the button has the same size as the table cell).